# Autoencoder Model Post-Training: How to make predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, autoencoder

I am new to deep learning model training and predictions, and I have a conceptual question about how to make predictions after training. I am following this tutorial on Github: https://github.com/jpark621/language-style-transfer. I have successfully completed training on my datasets, and a model was created in the models/ directory. The model contains trained weights, the loss of two autoencoders, and the adversarial loss.

**My question is that now that I have these .meta, .index, and .data files, how do I make predictions with the model by providing text as input?** The output would also be text (with the writing style modified by the Autoencoder model).

Any tips/resources/pointers would be helpful! Thanks so much.

Comment: Once you have a trained model loaded in, you typically make predictions by doing model.call(input) or model.predict_on_batch(inputs) if you have a batch of inputs.